# Why are my TIF files completely white when I export using GeeTools from Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, google-earth, google-earth-engine, google-earth-plugin

Here is the code I have been using in my Jupyter Notebook. GeeTools is installed and updated:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
import geetools

# Define an ImageCollection
site = ee.Geometry.Point([-72, -42]).buffer(1000)
collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").filterBounds(site).limit(5)

# Set parameters
bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4']
scale = 30
name_pattern = '{sat}_{system_date}_{WRS_PATH:%d}-{WRS_ROW:%d}'
date_pattern = 'ddMMMy'  # dd: day, MMM: month (JAN), y: year
folder = 'MYFOLDER'
data_type = 'uint32'
extra = dict(sat='L8SR')
region = site

# Export
tasks = geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive(
    collection=collection,
    folder=folder,
    region=region,
    namePattern=name_pattern,
    scale=scale,
    dataType=data_type,
    datePattern=date_pattern,
    extra=extra,
    verbose=True,
    maxPixels=int(1e13)
)
```

The export works, I get several TIF files appearing in my Google Drive. I then download these and attempt to view them in the Google Earth Pro app.

It correctly zooms to the location but the image is completely white, could it be that I am not specifying the gamma or range settings? If so, how would I go about this?